How to annotate zipping of dictionaries of differnt ypes?
I want to zip dictionaries into keys to tuples of values. I would be happy to annotate only for specific number of arguments, I will only use up to 5 ever.
from typing import Optional, Tuple, overload, TypeVar, overload

T1 = TypeVar("T1")
V1 = TypeVar("V1")
V2 = TypeVar("V2")
V3 = TypeVar("V3")

@overload
def zip_dicts(a: dict[T1, V1]) -> dict[T1, tuple[V1]]: ...
@overload
def zip_dicts(a: dict[T1, V1], b: dict[T1, V2]) -> dict[T1, tuple[V1, V2]]: ...
@overload
def zip_dicts(a: dict[T1, V1], b: dict[T1, V2], c: dict[T1, V3]) -> dict[T1, tuple[V1, V2, V3]]: ...
def zip_dicts(*dicts):
    return dict((k, tuple(d[k] for d in dicts)) for k in dicts[0])
    
a: dict[str, int] = dict(a=1)
b: dict[str, str] = dict(b="a")
c: dict[str, float] = dict(c=1.0)
d: dict[str, tuple[int, str, float]] = zip_dicts(a, b, c)
print(d)

However this fails with basedpyright:
• basedpyright: Overloaded implementation is not consistent with signature of overload 1
      Type "(*dicts: Unknown) -> dict[Unknown, tuple[Unknown, ...]]" is not assignable to type "(a: dict[T1@zip_dicts, V1@zip_dicts]) -> dict[T1@zip_dicts, tuple[V1@zip_dicts]]"
        Missing keyword parameter "a" [reportInconsistentOverload]
• basedpyright: Overloaded implementation is not consistent with signature of overload 2
      Type "(*dicts: Unknown) -> dict[Unknown, tuple[Unknown, ...]]" is not assignable to type "(a: dict[T1@zip_dicts, V1@zip_dicts], b: dict[T1@zip_dicts, V2@zip_dicts]) -> dict[T1@zip_dicts, tuple[V1@zip_dicts, V2@zip_dicts]]"
        Missing keyword parameter "a"
        Missing keyword parameter "b" [reportInconsistentOverload]
• basedpyright: Overloaded implementation is not consistent with signature of overload 3
      Type "(*dicts: Unknown) -> dict[Unknown, tuple[Unknown, ...]]" is not assignable to type "(a: dict[T1@zip_dicts, V1@zip_dicts], b: dict[T1@zip_dicts, V2@zip_dicts], c: dict[T1@zip_dicts, V3@zip_dicts]) -> dict[T1@zip_dicts, tuple[V1@zip_dicts, V2@zip_dicts, V3@zip_dicts]]"
        Missing keyword parameter "a"
        Missing keyword parameter "b"
        Missing keyword parameter "c" [reportInconsistentOverload]

that is true - there are no a b c keyword parameters. How do I overload * parameter without giving them names?

There must be a good dupe, I'll try to find one. You can make arguments posonly in overloads, so that their names are ignored: @overload def zip_dicts(a: dict[...], /) -> ...: ...

@STerliakov I found this one: Typing decorators that can be used with or without arguments.
